# How to update plot characteristics (hovertool details and x_range) in a bokeh plot multiple times?

Tags: python, jupyter, bokeh, ipywidgets

I have a bokeh plot that I would like to update the ranges (x_range and y_range) as well as the hovertool details (field names, etc.) when I update the source data in the plot. The things I've tried haven't worked yet. Any help would be appreciated. Here's an example of what I've tried.

```
def update_plot(*args):
    source = select_data();

    # Set ranges (not working)
    p.x_range = Range1d(0, source['x'].max())
    p.y_range = Range1d(0, source['y'].max())

    # How to change hovertool here?

figureTools = [HoverTool()]
p = figure(plot_height=600, plot_width=700, title='', tools=figureTools)
p.circle(x='x', y='y', source=source, line_color=None)

widget = widgets.Dropdown(options=['1', '2', '3'])
widget.observe(update_plot, 'value')

update_plot();
show(p);
```

Comment: There's lots of ways and places to use bokeh (standalone HTML, bokeh server apps, in the jupyter notebook, ...) so more context is needed to answer this question.

Comment: I'm using the jupyter notebook

Comment: You need to use `push_notebook`, there are example notebooks here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/howto/notebook_comms  You will need the latest dev build or the upcoming `0.12.2` release for those notebooks on `master`, there was a recent unavoidable change to the API to deal with notebook issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can put show(p) inside update, that works for me. 
For example,

```
def update_plot(*args):
    source = select_data();

    # Set ranges (not working)
    p.x_range = Range1d(0, source['x'].max())
    p.y_range = Range1d(0, source['y'].max())

    # How to change hovertool here?
    show(p);

figureTools = [HoverTool()]
p = figure(plot_height=600, plot_width=700, title='', tools=figureTools)
p.circle(x='x', y='y', source=source, line_color=None)

widget = widgets.Dropdown(options=['1', '2', '3'])
widget.observe(update_plot, 'value')

update_plot();
show(p);
```